# How to hide widget from certain category

Tags: categories, customization, widgets

I need some way to hide theme built in widget from one category.So when the post is from category X on that post hide that widget. I would use plugin for it, but since it's not drag and drop widget I can't. It's a ticker list which is built inside the theme. I have tried with `<?php if(!in_category('X')) : ?>` like I disabled one other, but this is `<ul>` list, and my solution ended with error.

This is the code with example what I've tried, and even tried to change position of this `in_category()` but no luck. Perhaps it needs to be done inside theme function with filter but i didnt find a way or code for it.

The code in `header.php`:

```
<div id="ticker">
<span class="ticker-heading"><?php _e( "Don't Miss", 'mvp-text' ); ?></span>
<ul class="ticker-list">
    <?php if(!in_category('X')) : ?><?php else : ?><?php $recent = new WP_Query(array( 'tag' => get_option('gd_ticker_tags'), 'showposts' => get_option('gd_ticker_num') )); while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>                       
</div><!--ticker-->
```

Comment: This line of code seems to do it, but also it removes it from Homepage and every cetegory page acrhive. So i am currently on 50-50 . I V tried with singular and changing place of ! and is / in_

Answer (score 1):

I think you might mean `is_category()`?

**Codex:** [`is_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category)

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with Wrought_steel's answer, that's the correct way. So the correct way is:

[`is_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category)

And your refined code will be:

```
<div id="ticker">
<span class="ticker-heading"><?php _e( "Don't Miss", 'mvp-text' ); ?></span>
<ul class="ticker-list">
    <?php if(!is_category('X')) : //just to hide something from Cat = X ?>
         <?php $recent = new WP_Query(array( 'tag' => get_option('gd_ticker_tags'), 'showposts' => get_option('gd_ticker_num') ));
         while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post(); ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
         <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>                       
</div><!--ticker-->
```

NO NEED to use an `else` condition, as you want something to hide if it's NOT the desired category.

Comment: Just seen what i wrote and edited my question, it was really late for me.What i want is, if the post is inside category X than on that post hide that widget. Thanks

Comment: What's the result when you tried mine? `if(!is_category('X'))`? Because `is_category()` returns boolean, it should have worked. If you want to show the `<li>` only in *this* category, just remove the naught (`!`) from the condition. Let me know what's the result if I'm on the right way.